# How to use loop in order to catch a tag name which has no specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please tell me two methods below to catch the `<table>` (line 3) which has no specific attribute like "id" or "class name" and input the first 3 rows `<tr>something1</tr>` `<tr>something2</tr>` `<tr>something3</tr>` with javascript.

**Method 1**: from the Top to the Bottom tag: `div` -> `div` -> `table` (subclass 3)

**Method 2**: from the Bottom to the Top tag: `<table id="Hero-WPQ1">` up to `<table>` (line 3).

```
<div id="content_data">
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>something1</tr>
                            <tr>something2</tr>
                            <tr>something3</tr>
                            <tr>something4</tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="ms-bottompaging">
        something
    </table>
    <table id="Hero-WPQ1">
        something
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y49F5/2/

Comment: **@Arun P Johny, zigs, Felix**: It works now but I would like to use the **loop** like this: `var a = document.getElementById("content_data");
var list = a.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
 //code goes here
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**:

```
var firstTable = $('#content_data table').eq(0);
```

or **[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector:

```
var firstTable = $('#content_data table:eq(0)');
```

or **[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)**:

```
var firstTable = $('#content_data table').first();
```

Basically, there are many ways to help you to get the first table as long as it's the first table inside `#content_data` in your case

---

For method 2, you can use **[.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** along with **[:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** selector:

```
var firstTable = $('#Hero-WPQ1').siblings(':first');
```

Comment: How about the method 2 - From the bottom with <table id="Hero-WPQ1"> to the top?

Comment: Please check my update. You can use `$('#Hero-WPQ1').siblings(':first')`

Comment: It now works very well to me but how can I apply the loop here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prev()` method like:

```
$('#Hero-WPQ1").prev().prev()
```

which gives you first table want you to desired.

for `<tr>something1</tr>` you can:

```
$('#Hero-WPQ1').prev().prev().find('tr:first')
```